# Miller: getting the row containing the max (or min) values

Tags: miller

Using miller, I would like to know what is the maximal value in a column (which is easy with `stats1 -a max`) but I would also like to get the whole row containing that max value.

Let's say I have this data under a `data.csv` file:

```
year,value,country
2000,13,ES
2001,18,IT
2002,16,TZ
2003,14,TZ
2004,10,ES
```

I would like a miller command to get the max row for each country (so something based on `stats1 -a max -f value -g country`):

```
year,value_max,country
2000,13,ES
2001,18,IT
2002,16,TZ
```

However `mlr --csv stats1 -a max -f value -g country` would only return the `value` and `country` columns not the `date` one.

I would like to do this in a single-pass as my data is quite large.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use top verb

```
mlr --csv top -f value -a -g country input.csv >output.csv
```

to get

```
year,value,country
2000,13,ES
2001,18,IT
2002,16,TZ
```

You have the `--min` option to have top smallest values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the verb I was missing!